# Synthetic control using library(Synth) error: Your panel, as described by unit.variable and time.variable, is unbalanced. Balance it and run again

Tags: r

Data (not all, I included  2 states, colorado is treatment, arkansas is a control)

```
    unit.num year        name          Y         X1
36         5 2000    arkansas 6.08529569         NA
37         5 2001    arkansas 5.27572930 6.08529569
38         5 2002    arkansas 5.39556315 5.27572930
39         5 2003    arkansas 5.76185695 5.39556315
40         5 2004    arkansas 5.70974286 5.76185695
41         5 2005    arkansas 6.50822319 5.70974286
42         5 2006    arkansas 7.26496681 6.50822319
43         5 2007    arkansas 6.95066084 7.26496681
44         5 2008    arkansas 5.74002089 6.95066084
45         5 2009    arkansas 5.97201850 5.74002089
46         5 2010    arkansas 4.83552692 5.97201850
47         5 2011    arkansas 5.44142359 4.83552692
48         5 2012    arkansas 5.96183948 5.44142359
49         5 2013    arkansas 5.27107340 5.96183948
50         5 2014    arkansas 5.15546247 5.27107340
51         5 2015    arkansas 6.00992410 5.15546247
52         5 2016    arkansas 7.08932889 6.00992410
53         5 2017    arkansas 7.95871591 7.08932889
54         8 2000    colorado 3.09689038         NA
55         8 2001    colorado 3.41189967 3.09689038
56         8 2002    colorado 4.03081592 3.41189967
57         8 2003    colorado 4.19543484 4.03081592
58         8 2004    colorado 4.72129806 4.19543484
59         8 2005    colorado 3.82133592 4.72129806
60         8 2006    colorado 3.72847942 3.82133592
61         8 2007    colorado 3.35146594 3.72847942
62         8 2008    colorado 3.27216431 3.35146594
63         8 2009    colorado 3.31845392 3.27216431
64         8 2010    colorado 2.88316463 3.31845392
65         8 2011    colorado 3.26059092 2.88316463
66         8 2012    colorado 2.98437286 3.26059092
67         8 2013    colorado 3.52908899 2.98437286
68         8 2014    colorado 3.08341017 3.52908899
69         8 2015    colorado 3.46654972 3.08341017
70         8 2016    colorado 4.02460169 3.46654972
71         8 2017    colorado 4.14893280 4.02460169
```

I start with 44 states, here is some code that i select the control and treatment groups

```
# vector to denote control and treatment identifiers  
controlid = c(1:56) 
controlid =controlid[-53] # washington
controlid =controlid[-52]
controlid =controlid[-43]
controlid =controlid[-41]
controlid =controlid[-32]
controlid =controlid[-14]
controlid =controlid[-11:-12]
controlid =controlid[-8] # colorado
controlid =controlid[-6:-7]
controlid =controlid[-2:-3]
```

```
# create matrices from panel data that provide inputs for synth()
dataprep.out<-
    dataprep(
        foo = formatted_synth_data,
        predictors = "X1",
        predictors.op = "mean",
        dependent = "Y",
        unit.variable = "unit.num",
        time.variable = "year",
        treatment.identifier = 8,
        controls.identifier = controlid,
        time.predictors.prior = c(2000:2013),
        time.optimize.ssr = c(2000:2013),
        unit.names.variable = "name",
        time.plot =2000:2017 # total data 2000:2017
    )
```

The Error

Error in dataprep(foo = Synthdata, predictors = "murder_pop_lagged", predictors.op = "mean",  :

Your panel, as described by unit.variable and time.variable, is unbalanced. Balance it and run again.

Answer (score 1):

"by balanced panel I mean that each unit of observation is observed in the same time periods. From your data I see that Alabama is missing one observation (all other states have 18 years in the data, Alabama only 17). The package internally builds a matrix of size (n_control_units, n_pretreatment_periods), which doesn’t work if control units don’t have the same number of pretreatment outcomes.

If you exclude Alabama it works:"
nilshg

https://github.com/efhart4/Syntheticdata

```
# vector to denote control and treatment groups    
controlid = c(1:56) 
controlid =controlid[-53] # washington
controlid =controlid[-52]
controlid =controlid[-43]
controlid =controlid[-41]
controlid =controlid[-32]
controlid =controlid[-14]
controlid =controlid[-11:-12]
controlid =controlid[-8] # colorado
controlid =controlid[-6:-7]
controlid =controlid[-2:-3]
controlid =controlid[-1] #alabama
```

```
# create matrices from panel data that provide inputs for synth()
dataprep.out<-
  dataprep(
    foo = formatted_synth_data,
    predictors = "X1",
    predictors.op = "mean",
    dependent = "Y",
    unit.variable = "unit.num",
    time.variable = "year",
    treatment.identifier = 8,
    controls.identifier = controlid,
    time.predictors.prior = c(2000:2014), #pretreatment periods over which the values for the outcome predictors should be averaged
    time.optimize.ssr = c(2001:2014), # minimize difference between synthetic control and treated in pretreatment period
    unit.names.variable = "name",
    time.plot =2000:2017 # total data 2000:2017
  )
```

> ## create matrices from panel data that provide inputs for synth()
>
> dataprep.out<-

- dataprep(
- ```
  foo = formatted_synth_data,
  ```
- ```
  predictors = "X1",
  ```
- ```
  predictors.op = "mean",
  ```
- ```
  dependent = "Y",
  ```
- ```
  unit.variable = "unit.num",
  ```
- ```
  time.variable = "year",
  ```
- ```
  treatment.identifier = 8,
  ```
- ```
  controls.identifier = controlid,
  ```
- ```
  time.predictors.prior = c(2000:2014), #pretreatment periods over which the values for the outcome predictors should be averaged
  ```
- ```
  time.optimize.ssr = c(2001:2014), # minimize difference between synthetic control and treated in pretreatment period
  ```
- ```
  unit.names.variable = "name",
  ```
- ```
  time.plot =2000:2017 # total data 2000:2017
  ```
- )